# Define which type will be used in a constructor

Tags: c#, generics, constructor

I would like to associate an object of type `AbstractObject` to my current Class.

However, this has to be done in the constructor, since, when I define my Class I don't know which type of object would be associated (only that this is of type `AbstractObject`). And I need to construct the associated object in my class (So I can't put an instance as parameter).

So it would be something like:

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(Type T) where T : AbstractObject
    {
        (T)Actiocator.CreateInstance(Typeof(T));
        //To do 
    }
}
```

but this doesn't work. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Why do you need it ? What is that you try to achieve ? Using reflection in constructor may potentially lead to issues.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your use case, there are several options.

#### Passing in the object

The simplest way is have the caller construct the object, and pass it in through the constructor:

```
public MyClass(AbstractObject template) 
{
    // Do something with template
}
```

#### Provide a static factory method

Expanding on the idea above, if you want to have control over the object that the constructor uses, you can provide a static method that creates a `Base` object and passes it to the constructor:

```
private MyClass(AbstractObject template) 
{
    // Do something with template 
}

public MyClass Create<T>() where T : AbstractObject, new()
{
    // Create a temporary object just for passing into the private ctor
    return new MyClass(new T());
}
```

I made the constructor private so you can create a new `MyClass` object only through the static instance:

```
MyClass.Create<Concrete>();
```

Also note I added the `new()` constraint, so I can simply write `new T`. This is fine if you know that `T` is going to a be a derived class of `AbstractObject` which is a reference type. If you want to be able to construct `MyClass`es from value types such as `int`, you can drop the `new()` constraint and use reflection.

#### Make the class generic

If you also need to store the object in your class, make the whole class generic:

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : AbstractObject, new()
{
    private T myObject;
    public MyClass()
    {
        this.myObject = new T();
        // Do other stuff   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a interface or a abstract class them implement it in the class you want to pass into the current class constructor

```
public interface ITest
{

 // your interface method and properties
}

public class Child : ITest
{
 // do your stuff here
}

public abstract class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(ITest tes)
    {
    // do stuff using test
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this would suit you?

```
abstract class AbstractObject {}
class Test :  AbstractObject
{
    public Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I work");
    }
}
class GenTest<T> where T: AbstractObject, new()
{
    T obj;
    public GenTest()
    {
        obj = new T();
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var genTestObj = new GenTest<Test>();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public abstract class MyClass<T> where T : AbstractObject, new()
{
    public MyClass(T type)
    {
        T instance = new T();
    }
}
```

If you add `new()` in the generics constraints, you can call the parameterless constructor of your class.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx

Comment: Note: downside of this is that you actually have to pass in a `T` which may be a temporary object whose sole purpose is to infer `T`: for example `MyClass mc = new MyClass(new ConcreteObject());`

Comment: C# doesn't allow constraints on non generic declarations

Comment: @nozzleman Error described in visual studio when I try to do it